# Generating a predictive distribution from a small sample

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have an oracle that gives numbers from an approximately-normal distribution, but I do not know the mean or variance of the distribution itself. (I do happen to that the oracle does not produce negative numbers, but I don't think that's super relevant. Typical values are between 500 and 2000.)

I have a small sample of size $n$ from the distribution already (typically 1-10). I am about to draw another observation, which we shall call $S$. I need to find a predictive distribution of $S$.

It's been a while since I took stats, so I'm hoping I can get someone to help me out a bit. My intuition is that I need to use Student's t-distribution, but I'm at a loss as to how exactly to go about it.

Can I just translate and scale it or something? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: You can use the sample mean and sample variance to estimate the distribution of S (which you assume to be normal)

Comment: You're misusing the word "sample": You have a small sample; not a small number of samples. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good point.

Comment: @citronrose Surely it can't be that simple!

Comment: @MrNerdHair: Why not? Maybe I didn't understand the question... If the sample is very small, your sample estimates will be poor and so your best guess. But there isn't much you can do about it, unless you have some other information.

Comment: If you want a so-called "predictive distribution" of the next observation, then it is indeed not as simple as what "citronrose" suggests, but if you want an estimate of the distribution of the next observation, that's another matter.  Then it is that simple if you're justified in your assumption that the population is normally distributed. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy What is that, and how would it differ from the underlying distribution? FWIW, I am writing a computer program, and I'm actually interested in the expected value of f(S), where f is an arbitrary function. I plan to take slices of the distribution of S and sum f(midpoint) * area_of_slice.

Comment: A predictive distribution would take into account the uncertainty in estimating the population distribution.  A Student's t-distribution would be involved in this. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy That sounds like what I need. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm a bit rushed right now --- maybe I'll post some details on this later. $\qquad$